# Json request is processed several times when activity starts in android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am new with Android, and it has been long time since the last time I coded. Sorry if this is a dummy problem.

My app asks the user to introduce indexed words that will be searched in an API. The user input is then used for creating a URL to request JSONObjects. This is done in the first activity. The second activity receives the URL and make a request to the API.

I am using a third party library to visualize the result in a Tinder-like Swipe-card effect view (https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards). This library has a method called onAdapterAboutToEmpty, where I included the JSONObjectRequest. I am also using Volley to create a RequestQueue.

However, this method is called three times when the second activity is created. I only need to call it once. So, my questions are as follows:

- Is this caused by the Activity lifecycle, or it could be a problem caused by the third party library?
- Can this affect to the app performance?

Here you have the code:

```
public class DisplayQueryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
ResearchAdapter mJSONAdapter;
SwipeFlingAdapterView mSwipePaper;
String user_urlQuery;
public int index_Springer_Query;
public int number_papers_deleted = 0;
static final int PICK_USER_ACTION = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_query);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Get data from previous Activity
    Intent intentDisplayQuery = getIntent();
    user_urlQuery = intentDisplayQuery.getStringExtra(UserInput.EXTRA_QUERY);
    index_Springer_Query = extractFieldQuery(user_urlQuery, URL_RESULT_STARTING);

    mJSONAdapter = new ResearchAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater(), getProviderLogoImage(user_urlQuery));
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    mSwipePaper = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.swipe_content);
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    mSwipePaper.setAdapter(mJSONAdapter);
    displaySwipeMode();
}

private void displaySwipeMode(){
        mSwipePaper.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {

        @Override
        public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {

            mJSONAdapter.remove(0);
            number_papers_deleted++;
            mJSONAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {

            Toast.makeText(DisplayQueryActivity.this, "Left!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {

            Toast.makeText(DisplayQueryActivity.this, "Right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
             sendJsonRequest();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(float v) {

        }
    });

}

private void sendJsonRequest() {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            user_urlQuery,
            (String) null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    mJSONAdapter.updateData(response.optJSONArray(VR_RECORDS));
                    Log.d("Console says: ", response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Log.d("Console says: ", error.getMessage().toString());
                }

            });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think my first question would be, why are you trying to send the json request in this method? Seems like a strange place to do that. You would obviously want to send the json request at a very specific time, where exact conditions are met. So a method titled "somethingABOUTtohappen" doesn't seem like a good fit for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NoChinDeluxe. First, I am trying to send the json request in this method because this is called automatically when the adapter has 5 elements. Therefore, as the user swipe right or left, the adapter has to be repopulated with new elements not previously requested. I am calling it here because it looks logic for me.

Comment: Second, at the beginning I only called onCreate and in the method onAdapterAboutToEmpty. However, when I was testing it, I realized that when the activity is created, the method is self-called. Therefore, I eliminated from the onCreate to not make the request twice. I have not created those methods. They are from a third party library. 
Could you develop on the way you would do it? I am very open to suggestions. I am new as I mentioned. Thanks again

Comment: Ah ok, that's what I figured. It's perfectly fine to call it there if you're getting consistent results, but if that were the case you wouldn't have asked this question :) I just know from experience that doing things according to things adapters do is usually scary and inconsistent, which is why I was curious if you had to call it there. If it were my code, I'd probably try to manually track the number of elements so I could just have complete control over that. But it sounds like you got it sorted out :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is always good to have any good feedback. ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, This behavior is very normal. The code is basically holding three items in memory. It loads in the first three, then when you swipe right it loads in the next item into memory and releases the first...

For example

1,2,3 are loaded into memory

You swipe right on number 1.

1 is then removed from memory and number 4 is loaded

You now have 2,3,4 in memory.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for welcoming :). I really appreciate it.

Comment: Just as an FYI for those downvoting - please explain why!

Comment: what do you mean. I haven't downvoting. Actually, I can't vote till I gain 15 in the reputation.

Comment: Someone else did, not you :)

Comment: hehehe. I thought you were talking to me.